# Using PayPal's PayFlow Pro Gateway - How can I get the batch ID?

Tags: paypal

THe developers Reference and Guide describes many Name-Value pairs but apprently none for Batch ID of a transaction. Why this ommision I do not know but I use the simple process of a Curl call as shown in the sample code on the site.

How can get the Batch ID with some elobrate use of the APIs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A batch ID is only going to show when the transaction is batched out at the end of the night to your processor assuming they are not host based.  However with test transactions, they are only tests.  The never get batched out to the processor, and will remain in a trans state of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Batch IDs are assigned after the transaction settle. This could be the next day or two days later. Or even three if you have a slow processor/bank.

Payflow Pro has a separate API interface called the Reporting API. There is a report called a Settlement Report that returns all transactions with Batch IDs. There is also a report called Batch Report which returns a summary of the batches with totals and dates.

Here are the Reporting docs: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_Reporting_Guide.pdf

I've written a Payflow library for Ruby that uses the Reporting API. You can also see how it works there. https://github.com/bypasslane/payflow-ruby